# How to get the path element of hovered scatter point

Tags: highcharts

When I hover an scatter point in a scatter chart, the mouseOver callback receive a event object, but I cant find the current point nor clientX/clientY in that object.

How can I get it?

Im using version v2.3.5 of highcharts

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    [...]
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            [...]
            events: {
                click: function(ev) {
                    [...]
                    scatterClick(ev);
                }, 
                mouseOver: function(ev) {
                    [...]
                    scatterHover(ev);
                },
```

Comment: Check `ev.clientX` and `ev.clientY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are handling the wrong event.  If you want the point information, set the the callback on the point `mouseOver` event.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tQuqq/).

```
   series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        x = this;
                        alert ('x: '+ this.x +', y: '+ this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
    }]
```

Comment: Do you know how can I get the hovered DOM(<path>) element?

Comment: @Rafalages, look at `this.graphic.element`

Answer (score 0):

In the mouseOver event on the series.data callback, 'this' refers to the point, so you hold be able to use

```
this.x;
this.y;
```

E.g

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
[...]
series: {
    data: {
        [...]
        events: {
            click: function(ev) {
                alert (this.y);

            }, 
            mouseOver: function(ev) {
                alert(this.x);

            },
```

Comment: No, "this" refers to the series object of the point, and there's no atribute x/y

Comment: Which event handler are you using?

Comment: 'this' hasn't 'point' attribute, it just have 'points' but it's an array with all points in serie.
I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Which highcharts event callback are you using? Show us some code